# How to make an Azure app registration with platform SPA via Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

We use PowerShell to set up an Azure deployment, which, among other Azure resources, creates an app registration.

The simplified code is as follows:

```
$appRegistration = New-AzADApplication `
    -DisplayName $applicationName `
    -HomePage "$webAppUrl" `
    -IdentifierUris "api://$webAppName";
```

To it, we add redirect uris, like this:

```
if ($redirectUris -notcontains "$webAppUrl") {
    $redirectUris.Add("$webAppUrl");    
    Write-Host "Adding $webAppUrl to redirect URIs";
}

if ($redirectUris -notcontains "$webAppUrl/aad-auth") {
    $redirectUris.Add("$webAppUrl/aad-auth");
    Write-Host "Adding $webAppUrl/aad-auth to redirect URIs";
}

Update-AzADApplication `
    -ApplicationId $applicationId `
    -IdentifierUris "api://$applicationId" `
    -ReplyUrl $redirectUris | Out-Null
```

This works great, and an app registration with the "web" platform is created. It looks like this:

[image: App registration showing Web platform]

My question is how can we get these redirect uris to be under the "SPA" platform, using PowerShell? Like in the image below, which was done manually on the Portal.

[image: App registration showing SPA platform]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks there is no feature in the built-in command to do that, you could call the MS Graph - [`Update application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) in the powershell directly.

You could refer to the sample below work for me, make sure your service principal/user acount logged in `Az` via `Connect-AzAccount` has the permission to call the API.

```
$objectId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$redirectUris = @()
$webAppUrl = "https://joyweb.azurewebsites.net"
if ($redirectUris -notcontains "$webAppUrl") {
    $redirectUris += "$webAppUrl"   
    Write-Host "Adding $webAppUrl to redirect URIs";
}

if ($redirectUris -notcontains "$webAppUrl/aad-auth") {
    $redirectUris += "$webAppUrl/aad-auth"
    Write-Host "Adding $webAppUrl/aad-auth to redirect URIs";
}

$accesstoken = (Get-AzAccessToken -Resource "https://graph.microsoft.com/").Token
$header = @{
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $accesstoken
}
$body = @{
    'spa' = @{
        'redirectUris' = $redirectUris
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/$objectId" -Headers $header -Body $body
```

Check the result in the portal:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, I had arrived at almost the same solution except that I was doing something much more complicated to get the access token. Thanks!

Comment: one change I had to make was to use the app registration's Object Id instead of the Application Id. 


Also, likely because of propagation delays, I got a "resource not found" when running `Invoke-RestMethod`. To overcome that, I switched over to `Invoke-WebRequest` and added retries and waits between them.

    $response = Invoke-WebRequest `
        -Method Patch `
        -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/$appRegistrationObjectId" `
        -Headers $header `
        -Body $body
        -MaximumRetryCount 3
        -RetryIntervalSec 10;

Comment: @floatingfrisbee I test it with `objectId`, forget to change the var name when copy that from your question, please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

There was a [similar thread](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/50976) where someone was trying to programmatically add the redirect URIs for SPA and could not do it because it defaults under the Web section.

He was able to resolve this by posting with Azure CLI to the Graph API:

```
az rest `
    --method PATCH `
    --uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{id}' `
    --headers 'Content-Type=application/json' `
    --body "{spa:{redirectUris:['http://localhost:3000']}}"
```

Comment: Thanks for that info. I did see that thread while searching for a solution but was hoping to be able to use PowerShell instead of the Azure CLI, as we already have an extensive PowerShell script we distribute for deployment. What I would need is a way to invoke the same REST call using Invoke-RestMethod or Invoke-WebRequest (which gets tricky because I will need to extract the access token)